# Springboot how to rotate log files on the server restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

Springboot how to rotate log files on the server restart.

I have the below entries

```
# LOGGING
logging.level.org.springframework.web=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=WARN
logging.file=/var/log/apps/myapp.log
```

I can't find any details here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Check out here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#TriggeringPolicies . You'd want a `RollingFileAppender` with `<OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>`, it looks like. I can't test it, so not putting this into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

As per the following link in application.properties regarding log files, the following are the configurations.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

```
logging.file.max-history=0 # Maximum of archive log files to keep. Only supported with the default logback setup.
logging.file.max-size=10MB # Maximum log file size. Only supported with the default logback setup.
```

Apart from the above, you can also check below the configuration based upon the server configured.

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true # Whether to enable access log rotation.
server.undertow.accesslog.rotate=true # Whether to enable access log rotation.
```

I would suggest to use Slf4j along with logback. You need to configure logback.xml and you can configure rolling file appender.

Comment: This would answer a question of "how to keep logs at 10MB max", but not the original question.

Comment: Again, the lines added just enable log rotation by specific server (only access log, at that), but logs are still rotated based on size and not startup, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

I got a rotation policy with setting a limit to the log file size and the same for the backup.

```
logging.file.name=/path/log/file
logging.file.max-size=10MB
logging.file.total-size-cap=10MB
```

IMPORTANT: it will keep just a backup file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the custom log configuration with **logback-spring.xml**.

> The various logging systems can be activated by including the appropriate libraries on the classpath and can be further customized by providing a suitable configuration file in the root of the classpath or in a location specified by the following Spring Environment property: logging.config.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your exact scenario but you can do this by passing env_variable when you start a server.. like your build version number and use that in your property file

```
spring-boot:run -Dbuild.number=1.x
```

And you may use this like

```
# LOGGING
logging.level.org.springframework.web=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=WARN
logging.file=/var/log/apps/myapp-${build.number}.log
```

Dont forgot to increment number everytime.